# How is data saved in excel?

Tags: excel

I am having some data processing issues, in excel.  Essentially what is happening is i have the following cells:

Cell

---

A     | B    |

---

what i want is cell:

---

|A B|

---

so what i do is write this equation =(A&" "&B). Which gets me the desired results, I then Save this data in a new cell as the result value.  My issue is when i run this result through an application through a program for my company i get an invalid result.  So what my question is, is how does excel save this data in the background?  Is it something along the lines of after i make the equation it saves it as a string or something ? I have been scratching my head at this one for days, any help would be super appreciated.

Comment: you could always take your formula cells copy them and right click paste special as values  in a new column, then the formula goes away as does the need for columns A, B and formula column as you now have the data combined as desired.  but if you must know change the extension to .zip open the zip file and you'll be able to look at the raw XML where the excel data is saved.

Comment: I believe it's in the SharedStrings.xml in the xl folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a formula inside a cell this will be calculated the next time you'll open the file.
You could:

- copy the results, right click on the mouse, paste special, values;
- block automatic recalculation of the formulas inside the file [as explained in this guide.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-formula-recalculation-iteration-or-precision-73fc7dac-91cf-4d36-86e8-67124f6bcce4)